# Developing Google like keyword highlighting on a rails search engine

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, search-engine

I am developing a [clustering search engine](http://www.bunch-it.com) and it is time to develop a Google like keyword highlighting. I made it with little Jquery code but is it the correct way to do that. And also google does not make distinction like characters "o - ö" and "g - ğ". How could I do that in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 0):

> And also google does not make distinction like characters "o - ö" and
>   "g - ğ". How could I do that in an efficient manner?

Transliterate the characters and find the offsets that way. I hope Ruby has some built in support for transliteration else you'll be hard pressed to find a good mapping.

Comment: I guess I need more specific "how to do" kind of answer. Thanks anyway, as a start point...